# Is there a way to copy and paste data while simultaneously increasing a number in that data each time?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, paste

Basically I have in my program -

```
    team[0].game[2] = loadvar[1];
    team[0].game[3] = loadvar[2];
    team[0].game[4] = loadvar[3];
    team[0].game[5] = loadvar[4];
    team[0].game[6] = loadvar[5];
    team[0].game[7] = loadvar[6];
    team[0].game[8] = loadvar[7];
    team[0].game[9] = loadvar[8];
    team[0].game[10] = loadvar[9];
    team[0].game[11] = loadvar[10];
    team[0].game[12] = loadvar[11];
    
    team[1].game[1] = loadvar[13];
    team[1].game[2] = loadvar[14];
    team[1].game[3] = loadvar[15];
    team[1].game[4] = loadvar[16];
    team[1].game[5] = loadvar[17];
    team[1].game[6] = loadvar[18];
    team[1].game[7] = loadvar[19];
    team[1].game[8] = loadvar[20];
    team[1].game[9] = loadvar[21];
    team[1].game[10] = loadvar[22];
    team[1].game[11] = loadvar[23];
    team[1].game[12] = loadvar[24];

    team[2].game[1] = loadvar[26];
    team[2].game[2] = loadvar[27];
    team[2].game[3] = loadvar[28];
    team[2].game[4] = loadvar[29];
    team[2].game[5] = loadvar[30];
    team[2].game[6] = loadvar[31];
    team[2].game[7] = loadvar[32];
    team[2].game[8] = loadvar[33];
    team[2].game[9] = loadvar[34];
    team[2].game[10] = loadvar[35];
    team[2].game[11] = loadvar[36];
    team[2].game[12] = loadvar[37];
    
    team[3].game[1] = loadvar[39];
    team[3].game[2] = loadvar[40];
    team[3].game[3] = loadvar[41];
    team[3].game[4] = loadvar[42];
    team[3].game[5] = loadvar[43];
    team[3].game[6] = loadvar[44];
    team[3].game[7] = loadvar[45];
    team[3].game[8] = loadvar[46];
    team[3].game[9] = loadvar[47];
    team[3].game[10] = loadvar[48];
    team[3].game[11] = loadvar[49];
    team[3].game[12] = loadvar[50];
    
    team[4].game[1] = loadvar[52];
    team[4].game[2] = loadvar[53];
    team[4].game[3] = loadvar[54];
    team[4].game[4] = loadvar[55];
    team[4].game[5] = loadvar[56];
    team[4].game[6] = loadvar[57];
    team[4].game[7] = loadvar[58];
    team[4].game[8] = loadvar[59];
    team[4].game[9] = loadvar[60];
    team[4].game[10] = loadvar[61];
    team[4].game[11] = loadvar[62];
    team[4].game[12] = loadvar[63];
```

I'm retrieving the data from a text file.
Basically, in the program, I'm having to copy and paste the same thing over and over again, and increasing the array number for the team and loadvar. Is there anyway I can copy and paste it, and it do the number increasing for me?

Comment: Imagine what you code would look like if you had 100 teams and 100 games.

Comment: Read about loops in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply *don't* copy + paste, rather use loops to do the incrementing numbers, e.g. `for`

```
int v = 1;

for (int t = 0; t < 5; ++t)
{
    for (int g = 1; g <= 12; ++g)
    {
        team[t].game[g] = loadvar[v++];
    }
}
```

---

I've kept `game` indexed from 1-12 as in your question, but I suspect you might mean to index from 0-11. Be careful of this common source of bug for beginner programming.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!
I can't believe I didn't think of this, you just saved me hundred of hours bro!
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to copy and paste, you can write something like this

```
int i = 0;
int j = 2;
int k = 1;
team[i].game[j++] = loadvar[k++];
team[i].game[j++] = loadvar[k++];
```

and so on. However the shorter and less error prone way would be two nested `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it out.